# How to print Requiered Rows in the middle of the table?

Tags: sql

Table Input:

```
NAME    ID  COURSE YEAR
arun    1   mca 1
anil    2   mca 1
sudheer 3   mca 2
santosh 4   mca 2
arun    1   cse 1
sunil   2   cse 1
raj 3   cse 1
naveen  4   cse 1
venki   5   cse 2
prasad  6   cse 2
sudha   7   cse 2
ravi    1   mech    1
raju    2   mech    1
roja    3   mech    1
anil    4   mech    2
rani    5   mech    2
anvith  6   mech    2
madhu   7   mech    2
arun    1   it  3
sunil   2   it  3
raj 3   it  3
naveen  4   it  3
venki   5   it  4
prasad  6   it  4
sudha   7   it  4
ravi    1   ece 3
raju    2   ece 3
roja    3   ece 3
anil    4   ece 4
rani    5   ece 4
anvith  6   ece 4
madhu   7   ece 4
```

I need to print middle rows like below example

```
naveen  4   cse 1
venki   5   cse 2
prasad  6   cse 2
sudha   7   cse 2
ravi    1   mech 1
raju    2   mech 1
roja    3   mech 1
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using. Dont spam tag various RDBMS.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the middle of the table". Rows in relational database are not sorted. The only way to identify the "middle" is to specify an `order by`  statement.

Comment: Is there any particular condition that you need to satisfy to get 'middle of the table' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from Your_table Where rownum between START and END;
```

Change START and END with the row numbers you want as output.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it is MySQL :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT start,end;
```

Replace start, end with the starting number and ending number.

Comment: Can you share the query?